# Cross join on two DataTables using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have problem in doing a cross join on two tables. Here is my code:

```
public DataTable JoinTable(DataTable piTable1, DataTable piTable2)
{
    if (piTable1 == null || piTable2 == null)
        return new DataTable();

    var joinResult = from parent in piTable1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                     from child in piTable2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                     select new {parent, child};

    return joinResult.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

I am getting the result as two `DataRowCollection`s, but it's failing to convert the same to a `DataTable`. How can I do a cross join on two `DataTable`s?

Comment: Join examples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

Comment: Hi its a nice example, but my problem is the table columns i will  come to know only runtime. So i cant check any condition

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to do it manually:
1) create result DataTable
2) add columns from both tables (keep in mind, that column names in input tables may have save name, so you need convention to handle that - like include input table name or smth)
3) and copy values from join result entity to corresponding columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public DataTable JoinTable(DataTable piTable1, DataTable piTable2)
{
    DataTable JoinTable = new DataTable();

    if (piTable1 == null || piTable2 == null)
        return new DataTable();

    var q = from parent in piTable1.AsEnumerable()
                     from child in piTable2.AsEnumerable()
                     select new 
                     {                                                      
                         property1 = parent.Field<T>("PropertyName1"),
                         property2 = parent.Field<T>("PropertyName2"),
                         property3 = child.Field<T>("PropertyName3"),
                         property4 = child.Field<T>("PropertyName4")
                     };

    JoinTable.Rows.Add(q);
    return JoinTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code which worked for me. I had to further convert the q in to array and then list and then table as i was not able to cast the q directly in to table. Below is the code which may help to someone.

```
public DataTable JoinTable(DataTable piTable1, string table1Column, 
DataTable piTable2, string table2Column)
{
     DataTable JoinTable = new DataTable();
     JoinTable.Columns.Add(table1Column);
     JoinTable.Columns.Add(table2Column);

        if (piTable1 == null || piTable2 == null)
            return new DataTable();

        var q = from parent in piTable1.AsEnumerable()
                from child in piTable2.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                    table1Column = parent.Field<string>(table1Column),
                    table1Column = child.Field<string>(table2Column),
                };

        JoinTable = ToDataTable((q.ToArray()).ToList());
        JoinTable.TableName = "ResultTable";

        return JoinTable;

    }

    public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)

        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```